# .Net Regex Balancing Group - Error when no space char

Tags: .net, regex

I have a problem with this ".Net Regex", which works when there is a space char either side of the "i" between the inner brackets but when not, I get an error.

Can someone help out please.

Regex:

```
@([._\w]+)\[\["((?:[^\[\]]*|\[[^\[]|[^\]]\]|(?<counter>\[\[)|(?<-counter>\]\]))+(?(counter)(?!)))"\]\]
```

String:

```
@Text[["  alert(e[i ]); document.createElement(e[i ])  "]]     //WORKS
@Text[["  alert(e[ i]); document.createElement(e[ i])  "]]     //WORKS
@Text[["  alert(e[i]); document.createElement(e[i])  "]]       //ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good pattern to deal with nested `[[...]]` is:

```
@([.\w]+)\[\["((?:[^][]+|\[(?!\[)|](?!])|(?<counter>\[\[)|(?<-counter>]]))+(?(counter)(?!)))"]]
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40(%5B.%5Cw%5D%2B)%20%5C%5B%5C%5B%22%0D%0A((%3F%3A%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%7C%5C%5B(%3F!%5C%5B)%7C%5D(%3F!%5D)%7C(%3F%3Ccounter%3E%5C%5B%5C%5B)%7C(%3F%3C-counter%3E%5D%5D))%2B(%3F(counter)(%3F!)))%0D%0A%22%5D%5D&i=%40Text%5B%5B%22%20%20alert(e%5Bi%20%5D)%3B%20document.createElement(e%5Bi%20%5D)%20%20%22%5D%5D%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FWORKS%0D%0A%40Text%5B%5B%22%20%20alert(e%5B%20i%5D)%3B%20document.createElement(e%5B%20i%5D)%20%20%22%5D%5D%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FWORKS%0D%0A%40Text%5B%5B%22%20%20alert(e%5Bi%5D)%3B%20document.createElement(e%5Bi%5D)%20%20%22%5D%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FERROR&o=x)

*(I removed unnecessary backslashes to make it more light for the eyes, you can continue in this way using the free-spacing mode)*

The problem with your pattern is : `[^\]]\]` that can't match a single `]`, in your case the `[i` is matched with `\[[^\[]`.

Comment: Thanks a million .. regex is not a strong skill of mine, and when I look at your problem description I can see and understand it, but to find it in the first places, I wasn't able to